# Код возвращает не то что я хочу

Tags: python

Я решаю задание курса по питону. Высшей школы экономики.

Мой код возвращает не то что мне нужно.

Вот задание.

> Дан список чисел. Выведите значение наибольшего элемента в списке, а затем индекс этого элемента в списке. Если наибольших элементов несколько, выведите значение и индекс первого из них.

**Формат ввода**

Вводится список чисел. Все числа списка находятся на одной строке.

**Формат вывода**

Выведите ответ на задачу.

**Примеры**

Тест 1
Входные данные:
1 2 3 2 1

Вывод программы:
3 2

Тест 2
Входные данные:
1 2 3

Вывод программы:
3 2

Общая логика моего кода такая. Я сравниваю первое число списка с i, которая проходит список от самого начала до конца. Если i больше либо равно первому числу списка то оно сохраняется в переменную s как наибольшее на данный момент и когда цикл заканчивается печатается наибольше число и его индекс.

```
spisok = list(map(int, input().split())) 
s = 0                                    #Переменная наибольшего числа
ind = 0                                  #Здесь будет храниться индекс наибольшего числа
for i in list(spisok):                   #Цикл в котором код проходит по всем числам в списке
    pred = spisok[0]                     #В переменную кинул первое число из списка
    if i >= int(pred):                   #Сравниваю i и самое первое число из списка
        s = i                            #Здесь будет храниться наибольшее число
        ind = spisok.index(s)            #Индекс наибольшего числа
print(s, ind)                            #Напечатать наибольшее число и его индекс
```

Я не понимаю что не так с кодом. Если я вбиваю 1 2 3 4 5 то программа выводит 5 4 то есть верный ответ. Если вбиваю 1 2 10 1 1 выдаёт 1 0, что не верно. 1 2 3 2 1 вывод 1 0, опять неверно. 1 1 10 2 5 вывод 5 4 неверно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
spisok = list(map(int, input().split())) 
s = 0
ind = 0
pred = spisok[0]
for i in list(spisok):
    if i >= int(pred):
        s = i
        ind = spisok.index(s)
        pred = i
print(s, ind)
```

но вместо ручного нахождения максимума лучше воспользоваться функцией `max`

```
spisok = list(map(int, input().split())) 
el = max(spisok)
print(el, spisok.index(el))
```

Comment: Задание такое. Про макс я уже знаю, но его не проходили. Так что не понравилось питону? Зачем выносить pred из цикла и сохранять в эту переменную i?

Comment: @MozozGm в вашем коде все значения сравниваются с первым в этом и ошибка, а в моем а pred лежит самый большой найденный на данный момент элемент

Comment: я думал цикл будет идти в любом случае вперёд и просто сравнивать с первым числом, а он останавливается или выдаёт не тот результат.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант:

```
my_list = list(map(int, input().split()))

max_ind = 0                               # индекс первого элемента
max_val = my_list[max_ind]                # значение первого - в max

for i, n in enumerate(my_list[1:], 1):    # перебор в нумерованном срезе от второго до конца
    if n > max_val:                       # только если больше:
        max_val = n                       # переписать индекс и значение
        max_ind = i
```